# Does multiple Spring bean listen to ApplicationStartedEvent at once during startUp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concurrency

There are three handlers registering themselves to interface registry(`Set<Interfaces>`) during start Up

Below is one class example

```
@Configuration
public class CardAdapterHandler implements PaymentAdapterListener {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceRegistry interfaceRegistry;

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        interfaceRegistry.setListener(this);
    }
}
```

2nd Class

```
@Configuration
public class CashAdapterHandler implements PaymentAdapterListener {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceRegistry interfaceRegistry;

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        interfaceRegistry.setListener(this);
    }
}
```

and so on..

**SpringBoot - 2.2.10.RELEASE**

Since multiple classes are listening to ApplicationStartedEvent, will multiple Spring bean listen to ApplicationStartedEvent at once?
Is there a chance of concurrentmodificationexception occurring during application startup ?

Comment: you mean, you autowiring that class in multiple places? Why dont you use that @EventListener in your spring boot startup class? it will load once.

Comment: Edited the reference code sample a bit. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: why don't you call it `addListener()`  and synchronize the modification of listeners list?